# SpatialLines instead of segments (spplot)

Tags: r, geospatial, lattice, r-sp

I'd like to use `spplot` + `sp.lines` (lattice) instead of `plot` + `segments`. Do you know a simple way to realise this, e.g. [R: Calculating the shortest distance between two point layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27782488)

```
library(dismo)  
require(rgdal)
require(FNN)

laurus <- gbif("Laurus", "nobilis")
locs <- subset(laurus, !is.na(lat) & !is.na(lon),
               select = c("country", "lat", "lon"))

locs.uk  <- subset(locs, locs$country=="United Kingdom")
locs.ire <- subset(locs, locs$country=="Ireland")

uk_coord <- SpatialPoints(locs.uk[,c("lon","lat")])
ire_coord <- SpatialPoints(locs.ire[,c("lon","lat")])
crs.geo<-CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")  
proj4string(uk_coord) <- crs.geo 
proj4string(ire_coord) <- crs.geo 

uk_coord  <- spTransform(uk_coord, CRS("+init=epsg:27700"))
ire_coord <- spTransform(ire_coord, CRS("+init=epsg:27700"))


g = get.knnx(coordinates(uk_coord), coordinates(ire_coord),k=1)
```

to visualise this

```
plot(uk_coord, col=2, xlim=c(-1e5,6e5))
plot(ire_coord, add=TRUE)
segments(coordinates(ire_coord)[,1], 
         coordinates(ire_coord)[,2], 
         coordinates(uk_coord[g$nn.index[,1]])[,1], 
         coordinates(uk_coord[g$nn.index[,1]])[,2])
```

can probably converted to something like

```
ire <- list("sp.points", ire_coord)

spplot(uk_coord, sp.layout=list(ire))
```

but is there a easy way to convert `segments` to `SpatialLines` i.e. `list("sp.lines", Lines(...))`

Comment: note: that user of previous versions of pkg:dismo should update before running this code. (And I get an error about non-finite coordinates in the ire_coord assignment.)

Comment: Needed to add an extra line after the one creating locs.ire: `locs.ire <- locs.ire[ with(locs.ire, !is.na(lat)&!is.na(lon)), ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `panel.segments()` from the `lattice`-package:

```
library("lattice")
spplot(rbind(uk_coord, ire_coord), auto.key=FALSE,
       panel=function(...) {
         panel.xyplot(...)
         panel.segments(coordinates(ire_coord)[,1], 
                        coordinates(ire_coord)[,2],
                        coordinates(uk_coord[g$nn.index[,1]])[,1],
                        coordinates(uk_coord[g$nn.index[,1]])[,2])
       })
```

Comment: thanks, I like this way even more than the `sp.layout=list(...)` style used often

Answer (score 0):

Understanding panel functions is more powerful than relying on `sp.layout` in `spplot` -- and so is using `lattice` or `grid` functions directly. The solution with `sp.layout` could look like this:

```
spplot(uk_coord, auto.key=FALSE, col.regions = 'black', 
  sp.layout = list(ire, 
    list("panel.segments", 
        coordinates(ire_coord)[,1],
        coordinates(ire_coord)[,2],
        coordinates(uk_coord[g$nn.index[,1]])[,1],
        coordinates(uk_coord[g$nn.index[,1]])[,2])), 
    xlim = c(-140000,700000))
```

note that it is not restricted to the `sp.lines` etc functions; in upcoming sp 1.1-0, quotes around function names can also be omitted.

`spplot` tries to plot attributes of features in color by default, which is not meaningful here, so what you basically want is an `xyplot` with controlled aspect ratio (`asp="iso"`).